# Comment count issues

Tags: wordpress

[image]
All (39) | Pending (23) | Approved (16) | Spam (0) | Trash (1)

I'd like the users to see only his/her own comments and count filter.

How can I also filter the Number?

i have used the below code

```
add_filter('the_comments', 'comment_filter');

function comment_filter($comments){
    global $pagenow;
    global $user_ID;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if($pagenow == 'edit-comments.php' && current_user_can('author')){
        foreach($comments as $i => $comment){
            $the_post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
            if($comment->user_id != $user_ID  && $the_post->post_author != $user_ID)
                unset($comments[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that "the_comments" hook is the appropriate one.
Have a look at the "wp_count_comments" & "pre_get_comments" these 2 are wp admin filters, which should do what you need.

Comment: Publisher seen other count number but comment only show his/her won 

For exampl all comment are 20 
- abc is publisher in his/her won comment only 3 
- when abc login his/her won dashboard , comment only show 3 but comment count number show 20 , how to filter this count number also ???

publisher dashboard 
All (20) | Pending (0) | Approved (0) | Spam (0) | Trash (0)